# Obtener evento coordenada mas evento del mouse presionado

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Plataforma C# Windows Forms

Tengo en mi formulario un listview tres botones de comando y tres controles timer.
En el listview capturo las coordenadas "**x**" y "**y**" del mouse pero también quiero obtener que evento del mouse presiona el usuario o si realiza alguna combinación de teclas **Ctrl + C**, **Ctrl + V**.

Los eventos deben de ser capturados en cualquier parte del escritorio o pantalla y guardarlos en el ListView para su posterior almacenamiento en una base de datos, cuando el usuario presione Stop entonces dejar de capturar los eventos y coordenadas del mouse.
Es una especie de Macro.

Actualmente ya tengo la captura de las coordenadas, ahora como puedo capturar los eventos del mouse y/o combinaciones de teclas ejecutados por el usuario?

Ejemplo del llenado del listview:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con esto voy grabando las coordenadas del mouse:

```
public partial class LearnCoordinates : Form
{
    ListViewItem lv;
    int a, b;

    public LearnCoordinates()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Tmr2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (a != b)
        {
            Cursor.Position = new Point(int.Parse(LstView1.Items[a].SubItems[0].Text), int.Parse(LstView1.Items[a].SubItems[1].Text));
            a++;
        }
    }

    private void Tmr1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lv = new ListViewItem(Cursor.Position.X.ToString());
        lv.SubItems.Add(Cursor.Position.Y.ToString());
        LstView1.Items.Add(lv);
        b++;
    }

    private void btnRecord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Tmr1.Start();
    }

    private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Tmr1.Stop();
    }

    private void LearnCoordinates_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        a = 0;
        b = 0;
    }

    private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Tmr2.Start();

    }
}
```

Gracias por el apoyo que me puedan brindar.

Comment: con evento del mouse te refieres a que quieres obtener las coordenadas cuando presiones ctr+c o ctrl+v?

Comment: Así es las coordenadas las estoy obteniendo ya pero de todo el recorrido que hace el mouse, ahora quisiera obtener solo la coordenada y el evento que ejecute el usuario y agregarlo al LitstView..
Por ejemplo en que coordenadas hizo el usuario:
MouseLeft
MouseLeft
MouseLeft
Ctrl +c
Ctrl +v
Entonces como puedo obtener esos eventos y coordenadas?
@mourazo

Comment: La idea al final de esto es que grabar las coordenadas y eventos que hizo el usuario, para después cuando el usuario lo necesite ejecutar el proceso pero en automático, lo haga la aplicación, ya que pretendo almacenar los datos del Listview a la base de datos. @mourazo